# Battlesnake - how to make my snake public

Tags: python

I've created a snake for Battlesnake on Replit, but I can only test it while I have the Replit webpage open (where all my code is: replit.com/@my-name/my-snake-name#server_logic.py). I'd like to be able to add my snake onto the list of public snakes that you can choose from when testing your snake — that way I can run/test my snake from any computer, without having to first log onto my replit account.

Does anyone know how I can submit my snake to be on the list of public snakes?

Comment: Step 3 and 4 [from the docs](https://docs.battlesnake.com/guides/getting-started#step-3-deploy-and-run-your-battlesnake) look like they have you covered. As a bonus, they have different cloud providers guide to hosting your battlesnake.